# What does it mean: Undefined variable: filter in ...?

Tags: php

Full error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: filter in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/test/tiltangle/dpd/query.php on line 104

line 104:

```
if (!($b1=="")) $filter=$filter." and  b>=$b1";
```

line 35:

```
  $b1=$_POST["b1"];
```

As you see it was defined.

Comment: `$filter=$filter`?

Comment: in line 104 it appends a value to the previous `$filter` value. If `$filter` is never defined before this line, PHP can't get its value to append the string (if the goal of the script is to append multiple times strings, there should be a `$filter = "";` before the loop to init a first value)

Answer (score -2):

I could imagine that your code looks like this:

```
if(...) { 
    $b1=$_POST["b1"]; 
}
...
if (!($b1=="")) $filter=$filter." and  b>=$b1";
```

So it is possible that the first if-Condition is false, so $b1 is never set.

Comment: It can be, (I did not want to put the whole code here),  I checked ,the value of the $b1 and the POST is working.  Before the POST there is only the DB connection part. Is there a way to post here the whole code? It is quite long.